# Finding the distance according to the latitude and longitude available, error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'start_station_latitude'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, latitude-longitude

I have the following code running on Ipython notebook:
[image]

I am trying to calculate km from 4 types of geolocations stored in 4 columns. It is `start_point_latitude`, `start_point_longitude`, `end_point_latitude` and `end_point_longitude`. Before that I've made a copy of dataset to store all changes with new data in the new dataframe. Beside the distance that I need to calculate I have a time during which this distance is covered. Unfortunately, I get an error message. Tried to change the data type from float to string and back. The error message remains the same.

[image]

Another error that I get when I make changes is pairwise(). I probably wrote the code in a wrong way. Where should I make changes in the code to make it work?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You miss-represented `X` and `Y`. In your code, they are a list of strings, hence the error. But you need to use the latitude and longitude from the previous cell, so you need to make your `X` and `Y` be like the following:

```
X = [trips1.start_station_latitude, trips1.end_station_latitude]
Y = [trips1.start_station_longitude, trips1.end_station_longitude]
```

### Edit

This is regarding the Error mentioned in the comments below. You need to calculate radians using `math.radians` of both `X` and `Y` like so:

```
from math import radians

X_radians = [radians(_) for _ in X]
Y_radians = [radians(_) for _ in Y]

result = dist.pairwise([X_radians, Y_radians])
# multiply by Earth radius to get kilometers
result = result * 6371000/1000
```

So, here is a working example and try to take it as a reference. You can download the data used in the following example from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/106K6YLFQ8NV03hOCy4gxC4_2zNBDgdha/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
from math import radians
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric


df = pd.read_csv("countries.tsv", sep='\t')
egypt = df[df["name"] == "Egypt"]
australia = df[df["name"] == "Australia"]

X = [float(egypt.latitude), float(australia.latitude)]
Y = [float(egypt.longitude), float(australia.longitude)]
X_radians = [radians(_) for _ in X]
Y_radians = [radians(_) for _ in Y]

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
result = dist.pairwise([X_radians, Y_radians])
# multiply by Earth radius to get kilometers
result = result * 6371000/1000
print(result)
#[[    0.        13232.2081954]
# [13232.2081954     0.       ]]
```

Which means that the distance between Egypt and Australia is `13232.208` KM

Comment: Hello! Thank you! I made changes, but now it seems there is another problem such as pairwise()

Comment: from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

X = [trips_1.start_station_latitude, trips_1.end_station_latitude]
Y = [trips_1.start_station_longitude, trips_1.end_station_longitude]

#X = ['start_station_latitude', 'end_station_latitude']
#Y = ['start_statition_longitude', 'end_station_longitude']

distance = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
distance.pairwise(X,Y)
print(distance)

Comment: The error is following:  ValueError
      9 distance = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')
---> 10 distance.pairwise(X,Y)
     11 print(distance)

sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pyx in sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.DistanceMetric.pairwise()

sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pyx in sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.DistanceMetric.cdist()

sklearn\neighbors\dist_metrics.pyx in sklearn.neighbors.dist_metrics.HaversineDistance.dist()

ValueError: Haversine distance only valid in 2 dimensions

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>  . It seems like it needs an array. Some people recommend to use numpy.log() function. But I have dataset with 4 columns full of data.

Comment: X_radians = [radians(_) for _ in X]

Comment: `X_radians = numpy.radians(X)` should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got suggestion how to calculate it and it worked. 
>   Thanks a lot to all of you for the help!
>   Here is a code:

'from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km

for index, row in trips_1.iterrows():
    trips_1.loc[index, 'distance'] = haversine(row['start_station_longitude'], row['start_station_latitude'], 
                                               row['end_station_longitude'], row['end_station_latitude'])'